# mac vscode ELECTRON RUN AS NODE launch error

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

After updating to the latest mac mojave (10.14.6) version, unable to launch vscode
getting the below error on trying to open from command line,

```
icudtl.dat not found in bundle[1011/104233.100549:ERROR:icu_util.cc(136)] icudtl.dat not found in bundle

ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the latest version of VS Code, if you are using brew update using brew command
use

```
brew cask upgrade visual-studio-code
```